# Will the proof become a spoof, if we replace'G is a simple graph' by ' G is a loopless graph'?

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

Will the proof hold, if we stricter the condition on simple graph? If we replace simple graph by loopless graph[graph without loop, it can have multiple edges or parallel edges]. Will the proof hold for this theorem? I don't see any wrong in the proof? Will the proof become spoof?

Comment: Misha has already posted a good answer, but I just wanted to point out that the only things you would need to change in Whitney's original proof to accommodate multiple edges is that the last sentence in the second paragraph would say $|\lbrack S,\bar{S}\rbrack|\geq|S||\bar{S}|$ and the second to last sentence in the last paragraph would say "yields at least $|T|$ distinct edges". Loops shouldn't affect Whitney's proof either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that the proof still holds.

If it reassures you, we can prove that parallel edges can't possibly matter to the inequality $\kappa(G) \le \kappa'(G)$. If $G$ is a graph with parallel edges, and we let $H$ be its "simplification" (deleting all but one copy of every parallel edge), then:

- $\kappa'(H) \le \kappa'(G)$, since every edge cut in $G$ remains an edge cut in $H$ but possibly has fewer edges in it now.
- $\kappa(G) = \kappa(H)$, since any set of vertices induces a connected subgraph of $G$ if and only if it induces a connected subgraph of $H$.

If we've shown the inequality for simple graphs, then $\kappa(H) \le \kappa'(H)$, and therefore $\kappa(G) \le \kappa'(G)$.

For that matter, loops will not affect $\kappa$ or $\kappa'$, and can only increase the minimum degree $\delta$. So the theorem holds for all kinds of multigraphs.

There's one caveat to all this. The inequality $\kappa(G) \le n(G) -1$, which we used in the proof, holds by convention, in a sense: we have $\kappa(G) \le n(G)-2$ for graphs that are not complete graphs, and we define $\kappa(K_n) = n-1$ even though there is no vertex cut of $K_n$. So if we want to deal with multigraphs, we had better define $\kappa(G) = n(G)-1$ when the simplification of $G$ is a complete graph, as well.